# Hyphenate "coal supply contracts"?

Tags: american-english, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Should "coal supply contracts" be hyphenated since "coal supply" modifies  "contracts"?

Example sentence:

Please provide a copy of the coal supply contract.

Comment: I wouldn't include any hyphens. [Nor, apparently, does anyone else.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coal+supply+contract%2Ccoal-supply+contract%2Ccoal+supply-contract%2Ccoal-supply-contract&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoal%20supply%20contract%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: There's little chance of this being construed as _supply contracts made from coal_, so the untidy hyphens which are often needed to disambiguate can be kept locked in the cupboard.

Comment: Your example is not a sentence and has no context: -- *"coal supply (verb) contracts (noun)", "coal supply (noun) contracts (verb)"*, or *"coal supply(noun)  contracts(noun)*?